# Merge two data frames and select specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I want to merge two data frames by a column Number. Also, I want to save the merged data frame in CSV file, but only predefined columns.

```
column_names_1 = [..,..,...]
column_names_2 = [..,..,...]

columns = [[column_names_1,column_names_2]]
data = data_1.merge(data_2, on='Number')
data[columns].to_csv("data.csv")
```

This code gives me an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a simple list to access `data`, not a list of list of lists. What you need would be -

```
columns = column_names_1 + column_names_2
data = data_1.merge(data_2, on='Number')
data[columns].to_csv("data.csv")
```